# Error creating EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to create a R4.xl EC2 instance and getting the following error:

> EBS-optimized instances are not supported for your requested configuration. Please check the documentation for supported configurations.

[image: EC2 R4.XLARGE error]

When trying to create the exact same instance for R3.xl, it well went through fine.

from what i know the only difference between them is that R4 can work only on EBS, and indeed in R4 config, it is marked to work with EBS:

[image]

any idea what can be wrong in here?

Comment: Check if you launching it in a VPC. Check if your AMI supports the instance type. Try launching it in a different availability zone.

Comment: thanks @helloV, I'm trying to launch it in the same VPC as other instances, and same happens with other zones as well.
how do I check if the AMI supports the instance?
btw, tries to launch it with the popular Quickstart AMIs, and got the same error for all of them..

Comment: To test that you are able to launch this instance, could you try launching it via the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/)? Here is a command for launching in the Ohio region (if you use a different region, use a different AMI ID): `aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-58277d3d --instance-type r4.xlarge --region us-east-2`

Answer (score 2):

For me, it was that the instance type I was choosing to use (m3.medium)  wasn't available in the region I was using (ca-central-1).  Kind of a cryptic message.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the issue with availability in that AZ. Can you try on the another AZ in that region. hope that will work. If not please post the image id here(If it is public image).